# How can I get the HTML5 validity state of an input text box?

Tags: html, validation

How can I retrieve the HTML 5 'validity' status of a text box?

For instance, I have a text input with `type="email"`. When the user enters the wrong value, the text box shows a red border (in Firefox browser).

How can I check the 'validity-state' of the input box?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `validity` property:

```
var isValid = document.getElementById('email').validity.valid;
```

Or `checkValidity()` method:

```
var isValid = document.getElementById('email').checkValidity();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdqMU/) | [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation).

Comment: Other functions for input validity: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api

Comment: Thanks that helps.. Is there an event like 'onvalid' to check the validity?

Comment: @promaxdev There is an invalid event

Answer (score 3):

There is an [event `oninvalid` for invalid input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid), you can register the event if you want to act on it.